# Why is my ImageUri not showing in my AlertDialogBox in setView?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a listview of students. What I want is when you long-press a selected list, an option list will show up using alert dialog. Options would be Show, Edit and Delete.

When the user will click **Show**, an alert dialog will pop up showing all the details of the student.

From my code below, the only one that is showing is the Lastname, first name and the course but my image which is an imageUri will not show.

Please check out my code below. Thanks!

MainActivity.java

```
    ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    private Uri imageUri;
    ListView lv;
    AlertDialog.Builder options_builder, show_builder, edit_builder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.student_listview);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, studentArrayList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

        //
        options_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        show_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        edit_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    }

    //for menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_add){
            Intent add = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddStudentActivity.class);
//            startActivity(add);
            startActivityForResult(add, 0);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    //inflate the menu

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addmenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //handles the onclick listener for the listview
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            imageUri = b.getParcelable("image");
            String lastname = b.getString("lastname");
            String firstname = b.getString("firstname");
            String course = b.getString("course");

            Student student = new Student(imageUri, lastname, firstname, course);
            studentArrayList.add(student);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{

        }
    }

    //handles when the listview is long clicked
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
//        final CharSequence[] options = {"Show", "Edit", "Delete"};

        //
        Student selectedStudents = studentArrayList.get(position);
        final Uri image = selectedStudents.getUriImage();
        final String lastname = selectedStudents.getStudlname();
        final String firstname = selectedStudents.getStudfname();
        final String course = selectedStudents.getStudcourse();
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

        options_builder.setTitle("Choose an option");
        String [] options = {"Show", "Edit", "Delete"};

        options_builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                    case 0:
                        show_builder.setTitle(""+lastname+", "+firstname+"\n"+course);
                        show_builder.setView(imageView);
                        show_builder.setNeutralButton("Okay", null);

                        AlertDialog show_dialog = show_builder.show();
                        show_dialog.show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent toedit = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddStudentActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(toedit,0);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        studentArrayList.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        AlertDialog options_dialog = options_builder.show();
        options_dialog.show();



        return true;
    }
```

Comment: check if your `imageUri` is not null

Comment: I have checked already and changed it to:         `imageView.setImageURI(image);` but still my setView() is still empty

Comment: same thing - check if `image` is not null

Comment: It's not null. Any other ideas?

Comment: what is it's value?